# Dataproc Job Submit Via API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have streaming job running which will run forever and will execute the query on Kafka topic, I am going through DataProc Documentation for submitting a job via Java, here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job)

```
 // Submit an asynchronous request to execute the job.
      OperationFuture<Job, JobMetadata> submitJobAsOperationAsyncRequest =
          jobControllerClient.submitJobAsOperationAsync(projectId, region, job);

      Job response = submitJobAsOperationAsyncRequest.get();
```

For the above line of code I am not able to get the `response` , the above code keeps on running ? Is it because it's streaming job and it's running forever ?

How I can get a response ? So to end user I can provide some job information like URL where they can see their Jobs or any monitoring dashaborad

Answer (score 0):

The `OperationFuture<Job, JobMetadata>` class has a `getMetadata()` method which returns a `com.google.api.core.ApiFuture<JobMetadata>`. You can get the job metadata before the job finishes by calling `jobMetadataApiFuture.get()`.

See more details about the [OperationFuture.getMetadata()](https://googleapis.dev/java/gax/latest/com/google/api/gax/longrunning/OperationFuture.html#getMetadata--) method and the [ApiFuture](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/api-common/latest/com.google.api.core.ApiFuture) class.